# Change picture in HTML using multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to have 5 images and 5 buttons, currently only the single button.
On button click I would like to show only the image that is associated with the button. for that I would like to write single function that gets the image path as parameter. I am very new to JavaScript, Bellow is a code I found and edited a bit:

```
<script>
    function pictureChange(path) {
        console.log(path);
        document.getElementById("theImage").src=path;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <img id="theImage" src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/18b5f8f0a00ad01e50f7ae2f513be52d/tumblr_msqcl4iwM01soh1p8o1_500.png">
    <p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange("http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png")"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently issue in you code is, when you passing string in function you need to the sequence of inverted comma's. for example while using "", you can use only '' single inverted comma's inside of it.

```html
<script>
function pictureChange(path) {
console.log(path);
document.getElementById("theImage").src=path;
}
</script>
<body>
<img id="theImage" src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/18b5f8f0a00ad01e50f7ae2f513be52d/tumblr_msqcl4iwM01soh1p8o1_500.png">
<p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange('http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png')"></p>
</body>
```

for showing 5 images, you can use single button too.
As per you requirement, **you can create array of images sources and pass index on button click**, as well as you can do the same which you were doing in your current snippet i.e **passing source on button click**.

Also, for single button what you can do is pass image src and find the index of that src index in array, from that index you change to next index and assign source to your image element. **Please make sure to check if you are in last index  than src at 0 index will get assigned, otherwise you will get stuck in error.**

updated snippet: css **display: inlne-block** property will help you. also you need to change the width of image, because by default it

```css
img {
  width:85%;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script>
function pictureChange(path) {
console.log(path);
document.getElementById("theImage").src=path;
}
</script>
<body>
<img id="theImage" src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/18b5f8f0a00ad01e50f7ae2f513be52d/tumblr_msqcl4iwM01soh1p8o1_500.png">
<p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange('http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png')"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it is working now! how can I place the button to be beside right-top of the image and not under it ?

Comment: hey chauhan, thanks but last snipped didn't work well. I would like to keep the image with their original size and just put the button besides the image, places at the top-right side.

Comment: Man, thing is when you apply your image in html, apply width as per your requirement, snippet is just to show you how you can do it.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but it doesn't work: here is what I tried

<style>

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>
<script>
function pictureChange(imgId,path) {
document.getElementById(imgId).src=path;
}
</script>

<body>
<img id="scene1" src="images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png">
<p><input type="button" value="4DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-4dof.png')"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="6DOF" onclick="pictureChange('scene1','images/scene1/scene1-6dof.png')"></p>

Comment: man i can see that its working. Copy your code, create a new html file and run it on you browser, you will definitely see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Now it's working, your "" were confusing the browser cause you can't nest with the same char, you must alternate " and ' when you nest

```js
function pictureChange(path) {
console.log(path);
document.getElementById("theImage").src=path;
}
```

```html
<img id="theImage" src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/18b5f8f0a00ad01e50f7ae2f513be52d/tumblr_msqcl4iwM01soh1p8o1_500.png">
<p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange('http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png')"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

U wrong on use symbols `"`.
Inside `onclick` function `pictureChange` u had symbol `"` then html throw syntax error.

u need use symbol `'` changing for `"`

`onclick="pictureChange('http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png')"`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Current error so far with your code

```
onclick="pictureChange('http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png')"
```

You got confused with quote. Wrap with single quote if your outer quotes are double quotes.

> currently only the single button. On button click I would like to show only the image that is associated with the button.

Just to make it more generic, pass the image id aswell.

```
function pictureChange(imgid,path) {
console.log(path);
document.getElementById(imgid).src=path;
}
```

And you can use it as

```
onclick="pictureChange('theImage','http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png')"
```